# Rewriting Git history to place all work in a subfolder instead of root

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a simple repository with linear history where work was done in the root folder. I would like to rewrite history so that all the work from every commit looks like it happened in the `/server` directory instead of the root directory.

In the end, the repository should have a single folder called `server` in its root, with all my project's files and folders now (and at all points of history before) located in `/server`.

Comment: This is a job for (old, now-deprecated) `git filter-branch` or (new, not yet part of Git distributions) `git filter-repo`.

Comment: A helpful blog post I found after this which interweaves multiple linear histories into one linear history, putting each repo in its own root folder like I requested in this question. The next step I personally needed, interweaving them, is the for loop code snippet that cherry picks them all. I'll put the link here in case it helps someone in the future. https://dev.to/detunized/git-fu-merge-multiple-repos-with-linear-history-4kci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '  
            toptree=`printf "040000 tree %s\\tserver" $1 | git mktree`
            shift
            git commit-tree $toptree "$@"
    ' -- --branches
```

Comment: For the record, I had to use WSL since cmd couldn't handle the multi-line input; and in Bash I first tried putting backslashes after each line to make it work with the multiple lines, but that isn't necessary (I assume because of the opening single quote). Just copying and pasting this exactly into Bash does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I am marking this as the accepted answer because it doesn't require installation of a separate program, it's built right into Git, and because the other answer with `git filter-repo` doesn't provide an exact command.

Comment: @Keavon Totally! You are the judge of your own answer-accepting. The explanation is a super-nice courtesy, and thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `git filter-repo`. This is just the kind of thing it was written to do; see #3 in the rationale section of the readme.

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#design-rationale-behind-filter-repo

Comment: git filter-repo reads one repository and then creates a new and different repository without touching the original, so you automatically get a copy, which is nice. I haven't experimented with filter-repo yet though.

Comment: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#moving-the-whole-tree-into-a-subdirectory